# It would have been a good idea for him to have gone

Tags: modal-verbs, perfect-constructions

1. *It would have been a good idea for him to have gone to that school*.

Does sentence (1) *alone* provide sufficient information for the reader/listener to assume that "he" didn't in fact go to that school? Or do I need to follow it up with another negative/positive sentence to make the intended meaning clear, as in:

2. *It would have been a good idea for him to have gone to that school. But he didn't go there*. Or
3. *It would have been a good idea for him to have gone to that school. But he went to another school*.

In other words, could I use (1) if I don't know whether he really went to that school?

Answer (score 1):

"It would have been a good idea for him to have gone to that school".

There is zero doubt that that sentence means "he didn't go to that school".

There is nothing else needed if you use that kind of conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use (1) if you don't know whether he really went to that school. It doesn't necessarily imply he didn't go to the school.

If you know for sure that he didn't go to that school, you can confirm it with an additional assertion:-

*It was a good idea for him to go to that school at the time, but he didn't*

Answer (score 0):

You can just use (1) as it clearly states that he didn't go to the school.

> It would have been a good idea for him to have gone to that school.

However, if you are not sure whether the listener understand what you mean, you can add additional information.